# Convert Stockfish analysis output to pgn

Tags: stockfish, pgn

It seems that there is no way to direct see Stockfish’s analysis in pgn when it evaluates a position. I am looking for a way to convert the SAN or LAN format into a PGN. Maybe it will work in Python. Does anyone know of a way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in chessbase you can right click on Stockfish (where it displays its lines of evaluation), and press "Copy to Notation".